# How to use 'LIKE' operator in MySQL to retrieve result of a query using the value of $_GET

Tags: php

I would like to query my database so that it shows me the result of the query based on my PHP's superglobal $_GET. I have tried this:

```
LIKE '%".$_GET["name"]."%'"
```

AND

```
LIKE '%{$_GET["name"]}%'
```

However, it was in vain. Can anyone help me with this?

This is my php code:

```
$places = query( "SELECT * FROM places WHERE MATCH (postal_code, country_code, admin_name1, admin_code1, place_name) AGAINST (?) OR LIKE '%".$_GET["geo"]."%'", $_GET["geo"]);
```

The error message shows me:

```
Fatal error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LIKE '%akutan%''
```

Comment: What was in vain? Got any error? first one's quotes not escaped prooperly

Comment: You should never put user input straight into your SQL query. Get the variable, escape it (or preferably use prepared statements) before using it

Comment: I have updated my question @MyWay

Comment: Ok, noted. Thanks a lot! @MagnusEriksson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not good idea to use global variable directly in your mysql query.

so, you must first assign it to some variable and use it

Like:

```
$getName = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['name']);
$mysql = "SELECT * FROM places WHERE `postal_code` LIKE '%".$getName."%' ";
```

I hope it will help you

Comment: I am working on an online course and I am not the root user on the appliance, I can't use 'mysql_real_escape_string'. It says here that access denied. I am aware that by not checking the special characters I am prone to SQL injection. However, this project is for the sake of better understanding php and sql. Thanks anyway!

Comment: So, just read the specs which states that '[no operator] implies or'. Thanks mate!

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
$mysql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE input LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['name'])."%' ";
```

Comment: Ok, noted. Thanks a heap! Could you please take a look at my php codes and the error message? Any way to rectify it?